# How to use reflection to find which namespaces are referenced by a class library?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, namespaces

For example...

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace Whatever
{
  public class SomeClass
  {
  }
}
```

If this is compiled into class library *mylibrary.dll*, I want to be able to use reflection to load *mylibrary.dll* and find out if it is referencing the `System.IO` namespace.

I've tried using `Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies` and then identifying namespaces in those assemblies, but this will always give me all of the namespaces defined in those assemblies whether or not they're actually referenced in *mylibrary.dll*. Since `System.IO` shares an assembly with `System` and many other important namespaces, this won't work.

Another thing I've thought of is to find out if a class from that namespace is referenced, but I can't find a way to do that using reflection.

This is for a plugin system, and the idea is to prevent the plugin from using certain namespaces, such as `System.IO`, by refusing to load the library if those namespaces are referenced.

Comment: have you started at least with a simple google search 
[C# reflection find namespace](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=c%23%20reflection%20find%20namespace)

Comment: Your example code is **not** referencing the `System.IO` namespace because it doesn't use any class from that namespace.

Comment: Yes, I have done that. Those all return classes DEFINED by the name space. I need to know what namespaces are being referenced. Completely different things, and I have not been able to find out how to do this using Google. So thanks for the down votes without fully reading and understanding my questions.]

Comment: @CrappyCodingGuy We understand your question perfectly well. Did you try Jon Skeet's solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549198/finding-all-namespaces-in-an-assembly-using-reflection-dotnet) (first result of DJ KRAZE's seach)?

Comment: No, you aren't understanding my question. If you look at Jon Skeet's solution, it's using `Assembly.GetTypes`. If you look at the documentation for that, it states: Resturns "An array that contains all the types that are defined in this assembly.".  It works wonderfully for that, and it will happily return the `Whatever.SomeClass` in my example. It returns types/namespaces that are **defined** in the assembly. That is **not** what I'm looking for.

Comment: Namespaces specified on a `using` statement are _not references_.  Only _assemblies_ are referenced.  Furthermore, `using` statements are only a design time feature.  There is nothing in the compiled MSIL for a using statement

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Thank you for understanding my question and actually having a discussion instead of assuming. After trying a hundred combinations of keywords for searching I finally ran across this which is looking promising: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821507/is-there-a-way-to-get-all-namespaces-youre-using-within-a-class-through-c-sha ...  Basically it involves using reflection to drill into the code and find every type that is being used.

Comment: I was going to suggest something like that but there's no way to know if the person who wrote the code put a `using` statement at the top or just used the full name of the class in the code.  I guess you could get the full type name and then everything to the left of the last dot would be the namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load the assembly in [Mono.Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/libraries/Mono.Cecil/). It will allow you to read the actual MSIL [opcodes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.aspx) in each function.

Some of these opcodes will reference classes: `call`/`callvirt`/`newobj` and the like. Read all arguments to each of these classes and you'll be able to make a list of the referenced types, which will in turn lead you to a list of namespaces.

## BUT...

Since you're trying o use this for security I must say it's not a good idea: this is easy to bypass. For instance you could use reflection. You could block the reflection APIs too, but then you could bypass it with compiled lambda expressions, or P/Invoke, or a mixed mode assembly... You could block them too but I don't think you'll be able to prevent every possible workaround.

What you should do, is load your assembly into a [sandboxed AppDomain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5998886/3764814) and let the CLR reject the insecure API calls for you. This is a feature that was actually designed for that purpose. It's implemented in the CLR and it'll be much safer to rely on it instead of your own solution.

Comment: Yeah, I was working through the code I linked to above, and I can see how there would be a lot of holes. The AppDomain concept is perfect, but this is running in Unity, and at least initial research indicates that Mono doesn't fully support AppDomain security.